# Using Alachisoft Ncache Open source's API to add object return "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: caching, ncache

When I start to using NCache open source version, I have using NCache API to store the object value.
 During the POC, when I add object into NCache, it always throws an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error message. And I am sure the object is not null.
Below is the sample code:

```
 /** For testing only */
            Cache cache = null;
            try {
                cache = NCache.InitializeCache("mycache");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
         response = ....

  CacheItem cacheItem = new CacheItem(response);
  cache.Add("testNCache", cacheItem);
```

Comment: Your cache was not initialized probably. Write exception output to console for debugging the real issue.

Comment: Create a new question for any more questions. This question has been marked as duplicate.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem is solved!!

Comment: Good to know. For any other questions post away on SO